# Show 100% of background

Tags: html, css, image

I have a navigation with a background like this:

[image]

I want to show the full height of this image in a height of 200px or something. This is what I have now:

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Stop motion</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li><a href="facebook.com"><img src="images/fb.png" alt="facebook"></a></li>
        <li><a href="twitter.com"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="twitter"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
nav{
    background: url(../images/navigation.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height:200px;
    padding:10px;
}
    nav ul{
        list-style-type:none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
        nav ul li{
            display:inline;
            font-family: 'ralewaysemibold';
            font-size:24px;
        }
            nav ul li img{
                width:36px;
                height:36px;
            }
```

But this is the result:
[image]

How can I make sure I see all the height of the image?

Comment: Perhaps you could make a JSfiddle.net example with your actual image but I don't think you want to center the image vertically..don't you really want it at the bottom?

Comment: Nice CSS indentation! Clever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this 
it must be so?
[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zyuxw)

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Stop motion</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
        <li><a href="facebook.com"><img src="images/fb.png" alt="facebook"></a></li>
        <li><a href="twitter.com"><img src="images/twitter.png" alt="twitter"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav{
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IHG6.jpg) no-repeat; /***change*/
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
    padding:10px;
}
    nav ul{
        list-style-type:none;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
        nav ul li{
            display:inline;
            font-family: 'ralewaysemibold';
            font-size:24px;
        }
            nav ul li img{
                width:36px;
                height:36px;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try background-size: contain , but could left you "white" areas depending on div size

Answer (score 0):

create one background image without dot with `repeat-x` for outer block. create another background image centered with dot only for inner div

```
<div style="background:url('repeatable.jpg') repeat-x top;height:200px;">
    <div style="background:url('dot.jpg') no-repeat top center;height:200px;">
       ...
    </div>
</div>
```

- [repeatable.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyEbf.jpg)
- [dot.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBhDP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
//use background-positon

 nav{
       background-position: /* x and y */

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

To show 100% of a background image, (at whatever size is required) you want to use the contain property not cover.

http://tutorialzine.com/2012/06/quick-tip-fullscreen-backgrounds/

[image: http://tutorialzine.com/2012/06/quick-tip-fullscreen-backgrounds/]

However, you might have better luck keeping the size at 100% and positioning the background position to be at the bottom of the div.

An antiquated solution would also be to slice that image into two divs, the top having a solid background color, and no image, the bottom div having the shadow and circle image background positioned and a fixed height. This adds cruft to your markup, but is a pretty solid method to get this look.